# AS3 - How to get function to run after currentFrame updates?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have 2 copies of a MovieClip (mcA) on my main timeline. Within mcA, I have 5 more MovieClips (mcB) and this code:

```
addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickedPoint);

function clickedPoint(e:MouseEvent) {
    e.target.play();
    setStat(e.target.parent);
}
```

So I toggle the frame of the mcB that was clicked, and I run a function that references the corresponding mcA on the main timeline.

In setStat, I call another function that checks the currentFrame of all the mcBs in the mcA.

```
getPoints(stat) {
    var points = 0;

    for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        if(stat["pnt"+i].currentFrame == 2) points++;
    }
    trace(points);

    return points;
}
```

My problem is that the setStat function seems to run before the currentFrame of the mcB that has been clicked on updates.

How should I change my code so that the mcB that is clicked on registers as having changed its currentFrame when I call setStat?

Answer (score 0):

You could call `setStat()` after the next frame update. A simple way to do this is to add an `ENTER_FRAME` event handler which removes itself when first invoked:

```
function clickedPoint(e:MouseEvent) {
    e.target.play();
    e.target.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(e:Event):void {
        e.target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, arguments.callee);
        setStat(e.target.parent);
    });
}
```

You can encapsulate this behavior in a function that behaves like `setTimeout`:

```
function callNextFrame(target:DisplayObject, callback:Function, ...params:Array):void {
    target.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, function(e:Event):void {
        target.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, arguments.callee);
        callback.apply(null, params);
    });
}

// Usage:
callNextFrame(e.target as DisplayObject, setStat, e.target);
```